# Parse does not exist in Android.Net.Uri

Tags: xamarin.forms

Xamarin (Visual Studio Community for Mac, 7.7.3) tells me Android.Net.Uri does not have Parse. In fact, the only things it recognizes are Android.Net.Uri.Builder and Android.Net.Uri.InterfaceConsts (editor assistant only shows these two items)

The line

Android.Net.Uri uri = new Android.Net.Uri.Parse("ontracktechapp2://");

fails with The type name 'Parse' does not exist in the type 'Uri'.
This is a Xamarin Forms app, and the class shown is part of the native Android

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using FindApp2.Droid;
using myappnamespace;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(FindApp2Droid))]
namespace FindApp2.Droid
{
    public class FindApp2Droid: IFindApp2
    {
        static FormsAppCompatActivity currentActivity = null;

        public bool IsApp2Installed()
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = new Android.Net.Uri.Parse("myurlscheme://");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, null);
            intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryLauncher);
            PackageManager pm = currentActivity.PackageManager;
            List<ResolveInfo> resolvedActivities = (List <ResolveInfo>)pm.QueryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            return (resolvedActivities.Count > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's a static method, you don't need "new"

Comment: Thank you! It's always those little things you miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was given by [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason):

> it's a static method, you don't need "new"

Comment: please try to mark your reply as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.